# Ubuntu Guest Account

Tags: networking

I have a problem with the Ubuntu Guest Account:
When I was trying to make a new connection to secure the WiFi network, it shows an error.

This [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syv1g.jpg) translates to

> Activation of the connection failed
>   (0) You can not connect an active connection to the device

I think it is a privilege demand. How can I fix it?
On my main admin account, everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the `Users and Groups` app, select the Guest account, click the Advanced Settings button, and try enabling the following...

[image]

Comment: I tried this option but didn't do anything.

Comment: @CinematicTree9  After setting this for the Guest account, did you log out/in of the Guest account and recheck?

Comment: Sure, I try but still have error :(

Comment: Can I remove these restrictions by entering a some command in the terminal?

Comment: In your admin account, open terminal and type `groups`. Then log into your guest account, type `groups` and see if there's a group that you need to add the guest account to.